# How to align text to the center of a parent Align widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having troubles aligning the text to the center of the box. 
I've tried to add `FractionalOffset.center` to align the column to the parent `Align` but it does not seem to make a difference. Since the second `Align` is within the first `Align`, I don't understand why `FractionalOffset.center` does not work.

Image:

[image]

Code:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Container(
      height: 30.0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: AnimatedBuilder(
                          animation: controller,
                          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                            return CustomPaint(
                                painter: TimerPainter(
                              animation: controller,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              color: themeData.indicatorColor,
                            ));
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            AnimatedBuilder(
                                animation: controller,
                                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                                  return Text(
                                    timerString.substring(2),
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                                  );
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: @pskink Hi yes, I saw and it works too, thanks ! While I was troubleshooting I also found out that the problem could be in my custom paint after all, as the width for the rrect was size*2. So I changed it to just size and I removed first Align. It worked fine after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could suggest you a lot of things, but I'll make something better. I'm gonna show you how to "debug" when you get stuck like this.

You see the lastest `Align` component? Wrap it in a `Container`, pass it a color, like `Colors.red` so you can see where this `Align` really is.

After that, you could do some workaround, since your child (Text) is not behaving like you're expecting, problem is it parent's fault. Remember this analogy.

With that in mind, you could check every component's father, first, your `AnimatedBuilder`, you could wrap it in a `Center` component, or do the same trick passing a color and wrap it in a `Container` to check where he is positioned after all in the Stack, and so on, and so on.

If is not your `AnimatedBuilder`'s behaviours fault, then check for his parent up in the tree till you find it.

Hope this have helped

Comment: Yes, this helped me more than you think :)) Thanks  ! I shall be using this method more often from now on.

Comment: instead of such "tricks" you can easily use [debugPaintSizeEnabled](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging) or simply press `"p"` after running `flutter run` command (`To toggle the display of construction lines (debugPaintSizeEnabled), press "p".`)

Comment: @pskink never used before, but I'll test it out, thanks

Comment: and you can turn it on from android studio too: see [Debugging visual layout issues](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#debugging-visual-layout-issues)